# How to change data label width in an Excel chart with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change a label width in Excel chart by VBA code:

```
set lbl = SERIES1. points(1).datalabel
msgbox lbl.width 'this is working

lbl.width = 40 ' compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

I can get the label width but cannot change it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the width of a chart data point label is not configurable. Even though the width can be retrieved with VBA, it's not possible to set or change it with a VBA command or property.

According to the documentation, the DataLabels.Width property is read only.

`Returns the width, in points, of the object. Read-only.`
[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/datalabel-width-property-excel)

Excel chart labels remain stubbornly uncooperative and resist formatting attempts, be it with VBA or with the UI.

That's (unfortunately) just how Excel works.

Don't shoot the messenger.

If you want to make a difference, consider raising an idea at [excel.uservoice.com](http://excel.uservoice.com)

Comment: Mikelowski claimed that he succeeded:

Comment: here is the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715554/resize-width-of-all-data-labels-in-every-chart-in-the-worksheet

Comment: first... i forgot to thank you :p... so thanks. second he uses FullSeriesCollection that i dont have in my excel 2010... maybe they fixed it in a newer version...

Comment: You can alter the width of a data label in 2016 (not sure about 2013), but not in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Excel 2016, you'll just need to adjust the series collection and point numbers to fit your needs.  `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Width = 363.314`.